# qml element id access from c++

Tags: javascript, c++, methods, qml

In c++ side I wrote this code

```
    :::::::::::::
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(rootObject,"changeText",Q_ARG(QVariant,"txt1"),
Q_ARG(QVariant,"hello"))
```

in qml side I wrote this

```
Text {
  id: txt1
  text: "hi"
}

function changeText(id,str){
        id.text=str
}
```

changeText function works in qml side but it doesn't work when I call it from c++ side. I think Cpp side method sends "txt1" as QString so changeText function doesn't work.

Can you tell me please how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way of changing properties of qml objects from c++ is to get that object in c++ and than call **setProperty()** method. Example:
qml:

```
Rectangle
{
  id: container
  width: 500; height: 400

  Text {
    id: txt1
    objectName: "text1"
    text: "hi"
  }
}
```

Note that you have to add a object name property that is used to get the child. In this example the Rectangle is the rootObject. Then in c++:

```
QObject *rootObject = dynamic_cast<QObject*>(viewer.rootObject());
QObject *your_obj = rootObject->findChild<QObject*>("text1");
your_obj->setProperty("text", "500");
```

You can compact this to one line call like this:

```
viewer.rootObject()->findChild<QObject*>("text1")->setProperty("text", "You text");
```

An alternative is to use the approach you had before but give object name to **changeText** method and iterate through the children of the main object until you find the one you are interested in:

```
Rectangle {
  id: container
  width: 500; height: 400

  Text {
    id: txt1
    objectName: "text1"
    text: "hi"
  }

  function changeText(objectName,str){
    for (var i = 0; i < container.children.length; ++i)
      if(container.children[i].objectName === objectName)
      {
        container.children[i].text = str;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks JuliusG but I have to change a lot of Text element in qml files from c++. Can you suggest easier way? Because always I have to write this 3 lines of c++ code for each Text element.